# How to compare two String in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need update my db data and the condition is to compare the old and new value.

The problem is the new value is a longer string containing the old value at db and I cannot find a way to compare them by a function like A contains B which A is new value and B is the old one at my db.

And I dont want to read the value from DB and compare by Java then if it matches, update the value. I think that will be heavy for treating a million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
where newvalue like concat(oldvalue, '%')
```

or

```
where newvalue like concat('%', oldvalue, '%')
```

The difference is whether the new value needs to start with the old value or just contain it anywhere.